# Activity indicator as a Toolbar item

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

How can i put and ativity indicator in a toolbar item ?
When the page is loading the ativity indicator starts running then when the page is loaded , the ativity indicator disapears and them the item that was in the toolbar item before appears.
Some apps have this implemented, apps like STEAM, is possible to do with xamarin forms?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just put ActivityIndicator into toolbar view?

```
<YourToolbarView>
<ActivityIndicator IsRunning="IsBusy" IsVisible="IsBusy"/>
<SomeOtherViewsInYourToolBar/>
</YourToolbarView>
```

I assume you already have your toolbar view created?

Comment: You mean this:
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem x:Name="Update" Icon="update.png" Order="Primary"  Priority="0" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

Thats how i create the toolbar items.

Comment: Ah you are using default toolbar. Try using the ActivityIndicator Icon and set IsEnabled Property to it. You will have to add this icon to your Resources obviously. Otherwise you can create a custom one and Add it on top of the page. Like Custom Navigation Bar for example.

Comment: I dont understand the first part, ActivityIndicator Icon?
Can you give ny example for the Custom Navigation Bar with the ActivityIndicator?
Thanks

Comment: You will have to get the Icon separately. As ActivityIndicator is platform specific. I just gave you example on how to make a custom one in my answer. Just create a view with all your items, and add it on top of the each page or in base page and then inherit base page in your all other pages.